# Pass React Native Promise between activities on Android [Kotlin]

Tags: react-native, android-activity, promise, kotlin, native-module

**FYI: I am new to Android world.**

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am using Native Modules for React Native Android. I am using [react native promises](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#promises) instead of callbacks to do some async task. Simple and Easy.

**In Detail**

I have a native module called "ReactNativeBridge" which has bunch of methods which are marked with `@ReactMethod` so they can be accessed from React Native side.

```
class ReactNativeBridge(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
@ReactMethod
printImage(imageUrl: String, promise: Promise) {
    val currentActivity = currentActivity

     if (currentActivity == null) {
        promise.reject("Activity doesn't exist")
    }

    // Start activity which takes promise as an argument
     val intent = Intent(reactApplicationContext.applicationContext, PrintActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(EXTRA_PRINT_DATA, somePrintData)
        putExtra(EXTRA_PRINT_PROMISE, promise)   // <---- here is the problem
    }

    currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
} }
```

As you can see I want to start a new Android activity in each of these methods and pass the *Promise* as an argument to those activities, through Intents. But I am unable to pass the *promise* through Intents since not all data types can be passed through Intents. I checked the type of *promise*, it is an Interface.

This is how a *Promise* Interface looks,

[image]

I know we cannot pass Interface since it is an abstract thing (like a blueprint).

** If your answer is "extend interface to Serializable" then remember I cannot modify Promise Interface. (It's a Facebook thing)

**Questions**

1. How to pass a Promise type through Intent ?
2. Is there any other approach to pass the Promise? Other than Intents.

Comment: Thoughts: Promises don't generally need to be passed around, however sometimes it is convenient/necessary to pass the means by which a Promise is fulfilled/rejected. In Javascript, this is not a problem because Javascript functions are 1st class objects and can be passed (within Javascript).

Comment: You are right @Roamer-1888 Good point. My thinking is *Intents* are a part of IPC mechanism on Android. And since promises inherently are not part of the Android, it's impossible for them to be passed around through *Intents* at some low process level. Feel free to correct me :)

Comment: What you say makes sense, though I'm no expert in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch). and resolve your promise when you collect the result you expect from the second Activity